# What's the difference between ref and type in an XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Consider the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="Root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Child" />
            <xs:element name="Child2" type="Child" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="Att" />
        <xs:attribute name="Att2" type="Att" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Child">
        <xs:attribute ref="Att" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:attribute name="Att" type="xs:integer" />

</xs:schema>
```

The `ref` to "Child" on line 6 fails, while the `type` on line 7 validates. For the attribute, the `ref` succeeds while the `type` fails. I'm trying to understand why.

My understanding of `ref` was that it simply referred to another element and specified that you expect to see an instance of the referred type (with the name given in the definition) at that location. Obviously I'm wrong, so what does `ref` actually mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using ref=".." you are "pasting" existing element/attribute defined on the other place. Using type=".." you are assigning some structure (defined in complextype/simpletype) to new element/attribute. Look at following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tst="test" targetNamespace="test">

    <xs:complexType name="Root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="tst:Child" />
            <xs:element name="Child2" type="tst:ChildType" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="tst:AttRef" />
        <xs:attribute name="Att2" type="tst:AttType" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ChildType">
        <xs:attribute ref="tst:AttRef" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Child">
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="AttType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="10" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:attribute name="AttRef" type="xs:integer" />

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: OK, I get that `type` can only refer to a type definition - that makes sense. But to clarify about `ref`: it can only point to a pre-existing instance of an element and inserts a clone of it?

Comment: Yes I think it could be said in this way (if "instance" mean some top-level element declared somewhere in xsd).
 
Another difference: when you use `type` then you can have two element with different name with the same structure. When you use `ref` then you have elements with either same name or structure everywhere.

Comment: From what I understand, it's a clone (for reuse) of the definition, it doesn't imply any "cloning" of the data in the document the XSD defines

Answer (score 3):

Within a content model, the `xs:element` element may be either:

1. An element declaration (giving the name and type of the element)
   or
2. A reference to a top-level element declaration (giving the
   name of the element as a way of identifying it, and deferring to the
   actual declaration for the type).

(The same name/ref alternation applies to attribute declarations and attribute references, and there is a similar dichotomy between inline type definitions and references to named types.)

In your example, there is no top-level declaration for an element named Child, so the `ref` attribute fails.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The significant difference between ref and type is that with type you cannot go further down a level, but with ref, you can use an element that can have additional level and so on.